# CMV Configurable Search Widget

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

Question about Search Widget:

As shown below in the snapshot the current search fields render as text boxes:

[image]

But i need to configure some of the search fields to render as dropdown lists as shown below in the expected design:

[image]

**So how can i configure the search fields to render as dropdown lists?**

Comment: you asked the same question within the github repo for the widget. I addressed your question there.